# vb6 how to count this and then use the 2nd to last one

Tags: vb6

```
Tre Dinga|models|3D model|Interior Architecture|Store space|Mannequins and clothing store supplies
demo|cool|Interior|Store|clothing store supplies
demo|cool|Interior|Store|clothing store supplies|Interior|Interior
```

As you can see I have `|`. I want to get the second string of one line. I've made 3 demo strings.

`dataa1` is the first line.

```vb
Dim output() As String
output = Split(dataa1, "|")
```

`output (0)` should output "models".

Now problem is using this code I have another issue. The issue is each line can have long or short sub sections so the `output (0)` will fail to get the second string and it will end up getting wrong string instead.

To clarify I want to grab second string regardless how long or short the sub section is.

Comment: The second string would be output(1).

Comment: Please clarify. Your title says you want the second to last one, your question says you want the second one, but your code sample you're using output(0) which would be the first one. From your 3 demo strings, what are you expecting the output to be?